# How to remove overlapping between labels in ITK snap?

Tags: vtk, itk, medical, labeling

I have 3 labels in for a 3D image. But one of the labels is also present (slightly) between the other two labels. Please refer the rough image below where I don't want the blue label to be present in between red and green labels ..rather I want to replace it with green label. I have been trying it solve this problem with ITK Snap and Convert3D software. 
[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpe4E.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an other software, you could load the image in 3D Slicer (https://download.slicer.org/) and use the Segment editor to "identify the island" and then update the value of the segment associated with the thin blue one. See https://slicer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/module_segmenteditor.html